# Can change position of a mesh using useRef but not with Cannon.js in React-Three-Fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, cannon.js

When I use `useRef` for access a mesh, I can change its position as this:

```
const [boxRef] = useRef();
...
boxRef.current.position.setX(boxRef.current.position.x + 1);
```

And it works! But when I use `useBox` from Cannon.js to give it a physic, it doesn't:

```
const [boxRef] = useBox(() => ({
  mass: 1,
  position: [0, 4, 0],
  velocity: [0, 1, 0],
}));
...
boxRef.current.position.setX(boxRef.current.position.x + 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second argument of `useBox`:

```
const [boxRef, boxApi] = useBox(() => ({
  mass: 1,
  position: [0, 4, 0],
  velocity: [0, 1, 0],
}));
...
boxApi.position.set(-2, 0, 0);
```